# Factory pattern returning objects that require other objects that are already created

Tags: c#, repository, factory

How do I handle the situation when my concrete object that my factory object will return relies on anther object that is already created.

In order for my repository to work, I need to have an instance of a connection object. I do not want to create a new connection object each time a repository is called. How do I handle this situation? Do I pass the connection object into the RepositoryFactory?

```
IRepository<User> userRepository = RepositoryFactory.GetRepository("user");

 public class UserRepository : IRepository<User>
 {
    public DbConnection Connection { get; set; }

    public UserRepository(DbConnection connection)
    {
        this.Connection = connection;
    }
 }
```

Comment: If you're using EF, are you aware that the `DataSet` and `DbSet` already implement [the Repository Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular example, it might be better to spin up a new connection each time, close and dispose when your finished using a unit-of-work approach to resource usage.

Answer (score 0):

In MEF, you would put a property on your factory object which imports a connection object.  The factory object could then provide that connection object as a constructor parameter to instances it creates.

The connection object could be constructed by MEF composition, or it could be supplied by the composition container (passed as a parameter into container.ComposeParts).